# Center object with jQuery and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to horizontally center an absolute positioned object with CSS and jQuery. The jQuery is necessary because the objects have varying widths. Mouse over the icons in my jsFiddle to see what I mean.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cb9A/)

Right now I have a `left: 50%` property applied, but I need to do a negative `margin-left` that is half of the object's width. This is my code, not sure why it's not working:

**jQuery**

```
$('.tooltip').each(function() {
      $(this).css('margin-left', '-'+($(this).width() / 2)+'px');
}​
```

**CSS**

```
.toolbar .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    display: none;
}

.toolbar li:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="toolbar">
    <li><img alt="Undo" src="undo.gif" /><span class="tooltip">Undo</span></li>
    <li><img alt="Redo" src="redo.gif" /><span class="tooltip">Redo</span></li>
    <li><img alt="Help" src="help.gif" /><span class="tooltip">Help</span></li>
    <li><img alt="Feedback" src="feedback.gif" /><span class="tooltip">Feedback</span</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There's a lot of extraneous CSS in your fiddle; it might help to simplify it more if you can.

Comment: Your `each` call, if you look carefully, [doesn't have a closing parenthesis](http://xkcd.com/859/). The code isn't running because it isn't syntactically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unclosed code mistake, updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cb9A/1/)

By the way, it has padding so you should use "outerWidth" instead of "width".You can corrected code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cb9A/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the block's width, I set `left` accordingly.

```
$('.tooltip').each(function() {
    // Assuming button block width is 32px.
    $(this).css('left', (32 - ($(this).width())) / 2+'px');
}​);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Cb9A/3/

Comment: Clever. This would work if the button had a consistent width, but it may change.